# iOS and xcode: how to implement the "dismissKeyBoard:" button method

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

This may seem like a very simple question, but can somebody please tell me how to implement the dismissKeyBoard: button method in xcode? I successfully followed other people's stackOverflow questions regarding making a keyboard toolbar and button, but when I click on the button to minimize the keyboard, the whole app crashes, and someone suggested it was because I didn't implement this method (which I don't think I did).

Here is the error I am getting:

```
MyApp[42902:907] -[ThirdViewController dismissKeyBoard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed6dac0 2013-05-07 12:47:29.206 ExampleApp[42902:907] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdViewController dismissKeyBoard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed6dac0' 
*** First throw call stack: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can you please tell me how and where to implement this?

Comment: Please don't post another question. You already have one for this issue.

Comment: Post your implementation of dismissKeyBoard:.

Comment: @rdelmar See his previous question (the duplicate). He doesn't have such a method.

Comment: I followed the answer I specified here, but I just get this error anyway. Thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the error message. Read it carefully:

```
-[ThirdViewController dismissKeyBoard:]: unrecognized selector sent
```

So ThirdViewController needs a method with *exactly* that selector:

```
- (void) dismissKeyBoard: (id) sender {
    // do something
}
```

If you don't have that exactly, you will crash exactly as shown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call resignFirstResponder on the textfield that opened the keyboard.

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
  [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I am still getting the identical error. Any ideas?

Comment: In ThirdViewController.m copy the exact code that is shown above.  Ill be shocked if it still crashes. Also make sure to not forget the semicolon after resignFirstResponder]